# Using tuples as indexes to compare items across a list

Tags: python

I have a list of three tuples and a list of three strings:

```
pairs = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
values = ['aac', 'ccc', 'caa']
```

I would like to use the elements of the pairs as indexes to compare the strings in the following way:

- The first pair of indexes, `(0, 1)` operate across the first letter of each string: `a` from the first, `c` from the second, and `c` from the third. That is, it compares the values at index `0` and `1` in the sequence `a, c, c`. Since `a` is lexically less than `c`, this comparison should give `'smaller'`.
- The second pair is `(0, 2)` and operates across the second letter of each string: `a, c, a`. Since they're both `a`, the result should be `'equal'`.
- Finally, `(1, 2)` is checked on `c, c, a`, resulting in `'bigger`'.

So the total expected output is the following list:

```
['smaller', 'bigger', 'equal']
```

I have tried the following code:

```
n=0
for x,y in pairs:
    if ord(values[x][n])>ord(values[y][n]):
        print('bigger')
        n+=1
    elif ord(values[x][n])<ord(values[y][n]):
        print('smaller')
        n+=1
    else:
        print('equal')
        n+=1
```

However, not only does it print the results instead of building a list, it also gives incorrect results (`smaller, equal, bigger`). How do I achieve my intended result?

Comment: What's the expected output? What's actually required?

Comment: My output should be a list with inside ['smaller','bigger','equal') wich i would use on later

Comment: @ibb Drat, I just realized that my edit is incorrect (despite it having been approved). It's not even internally consistent... I based the logic mainly on Alain T.'s breakdown, but I now see that the output they get is the same as what your *original code* produces, not your *intended* output. Can you please explain what logic is supposed to produce `['smaller', 'bigger', 'equal'`]?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension with the zip function to combine the two lists:

```
pairs  = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
values = ['aac', 'ccc', 'caa']

result = [ ("smaller","equal","bigger")[(v[x]>v[y])+(v[x]>=v[y])] 
            for v,(x,y) in zip(zip(*values),pairs) ]

print(result)
['smaller', 'equal', 'bigger']
```

- `zip(*values)` will create tuples with the nth character of each string:  `('a','c','c'), ('a','c','a'), ('c','c','a')`
- `zip(zip(*values),pairs)` combines those character tuples with each corresponding pair: `(('a','c','c'),(0,1)), (('a','c','a'),(0,2)), (('c','c','a'),(1,2))`
- these become `v` (the nth characters of each value) and `x,y` (the nth index pair)
- The appropriate keyword is then chosen in `("smaller","equal","bigger")` using the index 0, 1 or 2
- Python treats True as 1 and False as 0 when adding booleans (comparison results) so the index will be 1+1 if the v[x] is greater than v[y], It will be 0+1 if v[x] is equal to v[y] and zero otherwise. BTW, you don't need ord() to compare characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, there are just a few things to improve.

No need to compare the `ord`, you can compare characters directly.

Instead of printing, save each step in a list

You can use `enumerate` to enumerate iterables:

```
out = []

for n, (x,y) in enumerate(pairs):
    if values[x][n]>values[y][n]:
        out.append('bigger')
    elif values[x][n]<values[y][n]:
        out.append('smaller')
    else:
        out.append('equal')
out
```

Output:

```
>>> out
['smaller', 'equal', 'bigger']
```

*NB. I am not commenting on the global logic as what you ultimately want to do was not explicited*